# How to match spaces at the strings' beginning using QRegularExpression in qt?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I would like to extract digits from a QString containing space and common, and my code just like this:

```
QString line = "  3 , 50, 200, \t\t100, 70, +3, 5";

QStringList strList = line.split(QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+"));

qDebug() << strList;

// what I expect
// ("3", "50", "200", "100", "70", "+3", "5")

// while the result is
// ("", "3", "50", "200", "100", "70", "+3", "5")
```

As you can see, there is an unexpected `""` ahead when spaces are at the strings' beginning.

So my question is simple: how to edit the regular expression to remove the front spaces or common?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 2):

### **Title question: *"How to match spaces at the strings' beginning using QRegularExpression in qt?"***

Well, your code already matches the space at the beginning of the string. These are the matches:

"3`,`50`,`200`, \t\t`100`,`70`,`+3`,`5"

You need to understand how [QString::split()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split-3) works:

- If the first character matches, QString::split() will give you an empty string at the start of your result.
- If the last character matches, QString::split() will give you an empty string at the end of your result.

Note, you also need to watch out for matches at the *end* of your string:

```
QString line = "1, 2 \t 3 4  ";
QStringList strList = line.split(QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+"));
// Result: ["1", "2", "3", "4", ""]
```

You ask QString::split() to exclude the empty strings from your result, by passing the `QString::SkipEmptyParts` flag.

### **Other question: *"how to edit the regular expression to remove the front spaces or commas?"***

You cannot do this just by changing your QRegularExpression. You can exclude the empty strings, or remove the unwanted characters manually.

### **Final solutions**

You can ask QString::split() to exclude the empty strings...

```
QStringList strList = line.split(QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts)
```

...or remove spaces from the start/end of the string before splitting ([QString::trimmed()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed) does exactly that)...

```
QStringList strList = line.trimmed().split(QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+"))
```

...or remove spaces *and* commas from the start/end of the string before splitting

```
line.remove( QRegularExpression("^[,\\s]+") ); // Remove spaces and commas at the start of the string
line.remove( QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+$") ); // Remove spaces and commas at the end of the string
QStringList strList = line.split(QRegularExpression("[,\\s]+"))
```

Comment: Is this particular case, we could also use the 2nd parameter `QString::SkipEmptyParts`.

Comment: Great! It works! I have forgotten the case where spaces at the end. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @O'Neil I had forgotten about that flag! That's a much simpler solution. Do post it as an answer, and I'll upvote it

Comment: @JKSH Feel free to update yours which is already well detailed.